# How to get German day name from Carbon date?

Tags: php, laravel, locale, php-carbon

The German local is installed on my server, I checked with `locale -a`

[image]

This is what I tried:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE') or die('Locale not installed');
dd($user->created_at->format('l'));
```

it shows "Monday". However, the German word for this day should be "Montag".

I also tried

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE') or die('Locale not installed');
\Carbon\Carbon::setLocale('de_DE'); 
dd($user->created_at->format('l'));
```

but its still "Monday" instead of "Montag".

What am I missing?

Comment: which version of carbon are you using?

Comment: @Shobi Version 1.25.0

Comment: check the answer,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Carbon 1, use like the following

```
$newLocale = setlocale(LC_TIME, 'German');
$dt = Carbon::parse('1975-05-21 22:23:00.123456');
if ($newLocale === false) {
    echo '"German" locale is not installed on your machine, it may have a different name on your machine or you may need to install it.';
}
echo $dt->formatLocalized('%A %d %B %Y');          // Mittwoch 21 Mai 1975
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'English');
echo $dt->formatLocalized('%A %d %B %Y');          // Wednesday 21 May 1975
setlocale(LC_TIME, ''); // reset locale
```

[doc link](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-localization)

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, but as it came up on google as one of the top results. So here is the currently better option how to do this, without relying on the locales installed on a server:

It requires Carbon > v2

> You also may know formatLocalized() method from Carbon 1. This method
> still works the same in Carbon 2 **but you should better use isoFormat()
> instead**.

```php
Carbon::setLocale('de'); 
// Or as OP tagged Laravel just set locale to 'de' in  `config/app.php`
$date->isoFormat('dddd'); // Montag
```